# Garbage collector stops collecting the right amount of objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection, apache-kafka

I have a program which reads a huge file with 4 million lines with specified rate and sends these lines to the Kafka cluster. Here's the code of this program:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path.toString()))) {
    String line = null;
    do {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // rate is is the number of messages per second
        for (int i = 0; i < rate; i++) {
            line = br.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
                // asynchronously send to the Kafka cluster
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(Config.KAFKA_TOPIC, Integer.toString(getNextInt()), line));
            } else break;
        }
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        long sleepTime = 1000 - finish;
        if (sleepTime > 0)
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        else
            System.out.println(sleepTime + " is negative");
    } while (line != null);
    br.close();
}
catch (InterruptedException | IOException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

And it works well until this happens:

[image: Garbage collections per second]

GC stops collecting the right amount of objects and the program can not keep reading rate anymore. I tried to invoke `System.gc()` before `Thread.sleep()` but it didn't work always. What could be the problem?

Comment: Most likely the problem is in code not shown where. Kafka (or any messaging system) should have no trouble with 10 lines of message per second. It appears you have found a problem, but unless you think it's in this code, you will have to look elsewhere.

Comment: What does this chart show? The rate of messages sending or the rate of GC performed?

Comment: @AndrewLygin, garbage collections per second.

Comment: It seems you're using YourKit for profiling. It has a switcher between minor/major/all collections. What option is used in this chart? And what garbage collector do you use?

Comment: @AndrewLygin, "all" option is used in this chart. I use default openjdk garbage collector.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I used this program for reading without rate limit and it worked fine.

Comment: By default JDK choses collector based on the amount of heap size and number of processors available, so it's not fixed. Pleas, run your program with option `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` and check flags for `UseParallelGC`, `UseUseConcMarkSweepGC` and `UseG1GC`, one of them will be set. Moreover, lower gc rate doesn't always mean that the collector removes less objects from memory. Check 'Heap Memory' chart in YourKit to see if enough memory is collected.

Comment: How did you find out that _"the program can not keep reading rate anymore"_? It prints that the sleep time is negative much more often after 9:25?

Comment: @AndrewLygin, yes, it prints something about -2500ms

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at this problem from another perspective. Maybe, it's `producer.send()` that starts working slower after some period, so it generates less garbage and GC works less frequently as the result. Maybe, kafka can't keep the rate and is slowing down? Maybe lines in the file become larger and it takes more time to send them to kafka?

Comment: I thought about it, but as I already said I had run this program without rate limit and it worked fine. Moreover producer.send() is asynchronous, so it is not supposed to slow down.

Comment: @NikitaGorshkov are you are saying; using the rate limiter slows down the send() after 9:25, it takes about 250 ms on average?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, 2500ms for every "rate" number of messages

Comment: @PeterLawrey, @AndrewLygin, it turns out you are right, delays appear on `producer.send()`. I'll try to find out why it happens. Thank you very much!

Comment: So if the rate is 10 per batch, then the average per send is 250 ms.

Comment: What problem do you try to solve here? Are you afraid that your kafka cluster can not handle the amount of data? If that was your intension I guess you missed it. The only thing which is limited is the amount of records added to a batch within a second. `producer.send()` does not immediatly send the data to the broker. That happens async (as you already written in your comment.

Comment: Are you using a random int (`getNextInt()`) as key? That is waste. If you just send `null` as the partition key kafka will choose a random one for you.